# How to farm weapons with certain prefix?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm following this guide: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=438262074

which contains descriptions like this one

[image]

I've just finished the quest "Whoops", but the Sand Hawk that I received was not the same as the one in the pic (wrong prefix, no elements :(). Is there any way to farm for another one?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid there is not a method for guaranteeing the prefix of a quest reward gun (or any other part of it for that matter). Every aspect of the gun you receive is random, within a pool of allowable combinations.

People seeking a certain version of a quest gun, like say a flying sandhawk with Dahl parts, will probably be doing [save-quit quest farming](https://youtu.be/yxwPhAUargs).

This takes time, but it the only way to legitimately farm for quest reward guns aside from playing the entire game many times.